# Problems opening ASC files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ascii

I am trying to open an [.asc file](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/annual/solar/) (pick, for example, that one for 2014) from the German Federal Ministry of Transport and Digital Infrastructure. It contains information on the annual solar radiation. There are a few threads on problems with asc files but none of them helped me with this case. I tried Raster-Conversion-Translate (Convert Format) but that did not help either. The gdal command this windows genereates is

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:3044 -of AAIGrid __path__/grids_germany_annual_solar_Globalstrahlung_DE_2014.asc /Users/***/Desktop/dsada.asc
```

I got the following error.

```
ERROR 4: `/Users/***/Desktop/grids_germany_annual_solar_Globalstrahlung_DE_2014.asc' not recognised as a supported file format.

GDALOpen failed - 4 `__path__/grids_germany_annual_solar_Globalstrahlung_DE_2014.asc' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

I am using QGIS 2.8 on a Mac OS X with 8 GB of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not standard [Esri grid (.asc)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid) file. The correct format begins with

```
NCOLS ...
NROWS ...
XLLCORNER ...
YLLCORNER ...
CELLSIZE ...
NODATA_VALUE ...
```

And the header of one of them (grids_germany_annual_solar_Globalstrahlung_DE_2014.asc, for example) is:

```
[header]
Datei_Hersteller=DWD/KU1HA
Datei_Version=V001
Datei_Erstellungsdatum=21.01.2015 10:27:29
Org_Dateiname=grids_germany_annual_solar_Globalstrahlung_DE_2014.asc
Titel_1=Globalstrahlung
Titel_2=Jahressumme
Titel_3=auf die horizontale Ebene
Land=DE
Jahr=2014
Monat=
Bemerkung_1=weitere Erläuterungen siehe liesmich_format.txt und         
BESCHREIBUNG_gridsgermany_*_solar_de.pdf
Bemerkung_2=see readme_format.txt and DESCRIPTION_gridsgermany_*_solar_en.pdf
Bemerkung_3=
Koordinatensystem=Gauss-Krüger 3. Meridianstreifen Potsdam-Datum
Werte_Dimension=kWh/m2
Werte_keineDaten=-999
Werte_Minimum=936
Werte_Maximum=1225
Werte_Trennzeichen=Leerzeichen
ZeilenendeFormat=CrLf (Standard auf Windows Betriebssysteme)
[ASCII-Raster-Format]
NCOLS 654
NROWS 866
XLLCORNER 3281000
YLLCORNER 5238000
CELLSIZE 1000
NODATA_VALUE -999
```

The correct ASCII format begins after [ASCII-Raster-Format]

```
NCOLS 654
NROWS 866
XLLCORNER 3281000
YLLCORNER 5238000
CELLSIZE 1000
NODATA_VALUE -999
```

So delete all above and it works

[image]