# Reprojecting a Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, germany, desktop-gis, prj

I have a [.asc](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/annual/sunshine_duration/) file from the german DWD, which displays the sunshine duration in Germany.

through an [older post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138851/problems-opening-asc-files-in-qgis) I already figured out that in order to be able to work with the [.asc](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/annual/sunshine_duration/) file i have to change the header.

Now I can project the file, however the projection is off. 
[image: the wrong projection of the raster layer]

The picture displays a state in germany, so the raster-layer projection of germany should be much bigger and actually match with the state.

I am also sure that slecting the correct coordinate-reference-system would be able to fix the problem. However, i have only given a [.prj](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/help/gk3.prj) file with which I should work.

The .prj file reads:
*PROJCS["DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_3",GEOGCS["GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",DATUM["D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Gauss_Kruger"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",3500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]*

I would like to know how to project the [.asc](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/annual/sunshine_duration/) file correctly and if i will need the [.prj](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/help/gk3.prj) file for it. If so, how do I set up the KBS to use the [.prj](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/help/gk3.prj) projection for the [.asc](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/annual/sunshine_duration/) rasterlayer.

**I am using QGIS Desktop Version 3.4.1**

Comment: What is the raster file CRS if you check the properties of the layer? The .prj file is the projected coordinate system DHDN / 3-degree Guass-Kruger zone 3 which is ESPG:31467

Comment: If you select the above ESPG ID when you add the layer then that might do the trick

Comment: Loading in QGIS 2.18 using a 31467 based Gis-Project places the data correctly, without any fiddling with the data.

Comment: The default properties of the layer are set to an EPSG:3006 in the layer properties, so I will check to change to the 31467 ESPG ID

Comment: selecting the 31467 ESPG worked, thanks

Comment: How did you know the ESPG which should be used has a 31467 ID?

Comment: False Easting was set to `3,500,000`. The preceeding `3` indicates strip three of DHDN, strip `4` would have easting of `4,500,000`, etc.

Comment: ok, so it requires a more in depth knowledge about the CRS to know which one to use. So I will keep asking questions if they come up instead of trying to figure it out myself. ;)